# jQuery function in order to check checkboxes

Tags: jquery, forms, checkbox, checked

I need some help with jQuery.

I have a forms with checkboxes, e.g.:

```
<form name="myform">
<input type="checkbox" name="apple[]" value="12" />
<input type="checkbox" name="apple[]" value="12" />
<input type="checkbox" name="apple[]" value="14" />
<input type="checkbox" name="apple[]" value="15" />
<input type="checkbox" name="peach[]" value="12" />
<input type="checkbox" name="peach[]" value="14" />
<input type="checkbox" name="peach[]" value="15" />
```

Here is the jQuery that has been tried:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(":checkbox").change(function(){ 
        if($('.peach').attr("checked")) { 
           alert("Checked"); 
        } 
        else { 
             alert("Unchecked"); 
        } 
     }); 
 });
```

When I check a checkbox named "peach" I should be able to have checked also checkboxes named "apple" with the same value as "peach". So if I check "peach" with 12 as its value, then also checkboxes named "apple" with 12 as their value should be checked.

I am new to jQuery so I cannot find a solution by myself... would someone help me? :-)

Regards

Federico

Comment: You will get a much better response if you show the code you've tried, rather than asking for a full solution.

Comment: [SSCCE](http://robzu.com/sscce-short-self-contained-correct-compilable-example)

Comment: Well I know but this would be completely useless because I cannot even succeed in managing "checked" event. I gave a "peach-class" to peach checkboxes and tried this code:

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(":checkbox").change(function(){
        if($('.peach').attr("checked"))
        {
            alert("Checked");
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Unchecked");
        }
    });
});

But nothing happens

Comment: This seems to do it but it doesn't look even remotely useful http://jsfiddle.net/XhRGg/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$('input[name^="peach"]').change(function() {
    var apple = $('input[name^="apple"][value='+ this.value +']') // phew
    if (this.checked) {
       apple.prop('checked', true)
    } else {
       apple.prop('checked', false)
    }       
})
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MD7Jt/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle working link. http://jsfiddle.net/NfU68/

```
$('input').on('click', function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
    $('input[value='+value+']').attr('checked', checked)
});
```

Here instead of input you can use your own selector based on class or parent tags. I've used for demo purpose.

Comment: Thanks Vins, however I used Raminson's script which fits better my code! :-)

Comment: As you wish... I will suggest you to go for generalize solution rather then the specific to the problem which will affect your codes scalebility.

Comment: What problem you're facing with my code? Let me know I'll try to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution will attach an [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on) event handler to the `checkbox` elements to capture any `change` events.  It will then take the `value` of the current `checkbox` element and check all other `checkbox` elements that contain that value.

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {
    $('input[value='+this.value+']').attr('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/z6H7j/

For versions prior to 1.7, use [`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate) instead as `on()` did not exist at that point.

```
$(document).delegate('input[type="checkbox"]', 'change', function() {
    $('input[value='+this.value+']').attr('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8mQwV/

Comment: Thanks Rob, I tried your solution but I succeded better in using Raminson's script